# Caret browsing in Google search in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-search, browsing, caret

I used to do a google search then hit tab and browse results with the arrow keys. At sometime that didn't work any more and I don't know why. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that you have to have "instant predictions" enabled for this.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained **how** to enable "instant predictions"